# Efficient counting of occurrences in a range

Tags: c++, algorithm

> You want to collect information while student grades are being processed. School students have default list numbers "1, 2, 3, 4..." and the program must process the following instructions:
>
> 1. REGISTER (**c**): Register that the next student on the list obtained a grade **c**.
> 2. COUNT (**c, i, j**): Count how many students with a grade of **c** there are between [**i, j**] (inclusive).
>
> *INPUT:*
> An integer **N** followed by the **N** instructions to process. You can assume that *0 <= N <= 100000*, grades are between 0 and 100, and all list number ranges will refer to already registered students.
>
> *OUTPUT:*
> The corresponding value for each *COUNT* instruction.
>
> *EXAMPLE:*
>
> - Input:
>
>   ```
>   7
>   REGISTER 8
>   REGISTER 7
>   REGISTER 8
>   COUNT 8 1 2
>   COUNT 8 1 3
>   REGISTER 7
>   COUNT 7 1 2
>   ```
> - Output:
>
>   ```
>   1
>   2
>   1
>   ```

As you can imagine, this is an internet problem ([this one](https://omegaup.com/arena/problem/Procesando-calificaciones-de-alu?fromLogin=#problems)) and I came up with this solution:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);

    std::vector<short> A;
    int N;

    std::cin >> N;
    while (N--) {
        std::string W;

        std::cin >> W;
        if (W == "REGISTER") {
            short C;

            std::cin >> C;
            A.push_back(C);
        } else {
            int I, J;
            short C;

            std::cin >> C >> I >> J;
            std::cout << std::count(A.begin() + I - 1, A.begin() + J, C)
                      << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Apparently my code is very slow. Could someone help me find a more efficient solution? I've been thinking for quite some time and I just can't find a way.

Comment: Your code has all the hallmarks of being written for a competitive coding site (be aware that you will pick up some very bad habits on those sites).  These are not needed :  std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);,  std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); In the end the counting should not be done in the inner loop of your program. Another issue with competitive sites, they run your code on a system you have no control over so all the timings are very unreliable and should not be trusted too much. All in all  if you want to learn C++ get a good book or goto sites like learncpp.com

Comment: @PepijnKramer I had never heard of that page, I just reviewed it and it comes prefect to me. Thank you.

Comment: Hey good to hear that! I was half afraid I scared you with my comments (but there is a difference between problem solving and writing C++) ;) Oh and if you have questions, or problems post a question and we'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to implement 3 solutions for you. First `SolveSimple()` is same as yours, I made it for reference to test correctness of two others. Second `SolveBinSearch()` is based on [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) approach. Third `SolveDynProg()` is based on [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach.

Simple solution (same like yours) is about `10x` times slower than other two. Binary search is about `2x` faster than dynamic programming variant. Binary search variant is also considerably more memory-economic than dyn prog, but for the case of `100 K` instructions this memory economy is not a big issue.

Tests in my code are randomly generated. You can tweak number of test instructions `num_instructions` and `max_grade`, also flag `verbose` controls if to output extra debug information like answers of each method. After code you'll find timings.

Each of three methods accepts input and output stream, you can just pass in standard input and output, like `SolveBinSearch(std::cin, std::cout);`, in the case of sending solutiont to online contest judging system.

If to choose then `SolveBinSearch()` is the fastest and memory economic solution.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/Ybj1nT6Gx)

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>

using std::size_t;
using u8 = uint8_t;
using u32 = uint32_t;

void SolveSimple(std::istream & inp, std::ostream & out) {
    std::vector<u8> grades;
    while (inp) {
        std::string cmd;
        inp >> cmd;
        if (cmd == "REGISTER") {
            size_t grade = 0;
            inp >> grade;
            grades.push_back(grade);
        } else if (cmd == "COUNT") {
            size_t grade = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
            inp >> grade >> i >> j;
            out << std::count(grades.begin() + (i - 1),
                grades.begin() + j, grade) << std::endl;
        } else
            break;
    }
}

void SolveBinSearch(std::istream & inp, std::ostream & out) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm
    std::vector<std::vector<u32>> cnts(101);
    size_t cnt = 0;
    while (inp) {
        std::string cmd;
        inp >> cmd;
        if (cmd == "REGISTER") {
            size_t grade = 0;
            inp >> grade;
            cnts[grade].push_back(cnt);
            ++cnt;
        } else if (cmd == "COUNT") {
            size_t grade = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
            inp >> grade >> i >> j;
            auto begin = std::lower_bound(
                cnts[grade].begin(), cnts[grade].end(), i - 1);
            auto end = std::upper_bound(
                cnts[grade].begin(), cnts[grade].end(), j - 1);
            out << (end - begin) << std::endl;
        } else
            break;
    }
}

void SolveDynProg(std::istream & inp, std::ostream & out) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming
    std::vector<std::array<u32, 101>> cnts(1);
    while (inp) {
        std::string cmd;
        inp >> cmd;
        if (cmd == "REGISTER") {
            size_t grade = 0;
            inp >> grade;
            cnts.push_back(cnts.back());
            ++cnts.back()[grade];
        } else if (cmd == "COUNT") {
            size_t grade = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
            inp >> grade >> i >> j;
            out << cnts[j][grade] - cnts[i - 1][grade] << std::endl;
        } else
            break;
    }
}

void Test() {
    bool constexpr verbose = 0;
    size_t constexpr num_instructions = 100000, max_grade = 100;

    auto TimeCur = []{
        return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    };
    auto const gtb = TimeCur();
    auto Time = [&]{
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
            TimeCur() - gtb).count() / 1000000.0;
    };

    std::mt19937_64 rng{123};
    std::stringstream inp;
    size_t cnt = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_instructions; ++i) {
        if ((rng() & 1) || (cnt == 0)) {
            ++cnt;
            inp << "REGISTER " << rng() % (max_grade + 1) << std::endl;
        } else {
            size_t a = rng() % cnt + 1, b = rng() % cnt + 1;
            if (a > b)
                std::swap(a, b);
            inp << "COUNT " << rng() % (max_grade + 1) << " "
                << a << " " << b << std::endl;
        }
    }
    auto inp_str = inp.str();
    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "Input: " << std::endl
            << inp.str() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::boolalpha;
    double tb = 0;
    std::stringstream out_simple, out_binsearch, out_dynprog;

    tb = Time(); inp.clear(); inp.str(inp_str);
    SolveSimple(inp, out_simple);
    std::cout << "Simple time " << (Time() - tb) << std::endl;

    tb = Time(); inp.clear(); inp.str(inp_str);
    SolveBinSearch(inp, out_binsearch);
    std::cout << "BinSearch time " << (Time() - tb) << std::endl;

    tb = Time(); inp.clear(); inp.str(inp_str);
    SolveDynProg(inp, out_dynprog);
    std::cout << "DynProg time " << (Time() - tb) << std::endl;

    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "Simple: " << std::endl
            << out_simple.str() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "BinSearch: " << std::endl
            << out_binsearch.str() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "DynProg: " << std::endl
            << out_dynprog.str() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Simple == BinSearch: "
        << (out_simple.str() == out_binsearch.str()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Simple == DynProg: "
        << (out_simple.str() == out_dynprog.str()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "BinSearch == DynProg: "
        << (out_binsearch.str() == out_dynprog.str()) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Test();
}
```

Output:

```
Simple time 0.184678
BinSearch time 0.020600
DynProg time 0.048994
Simple == BinSearch: true
Simple == DynProg: true
BinSearch == DynProg: true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been going through all three solutions and of course I stick with the binary search implementation, but the dynamic solution also seemed interesting to me

Comment: @DiegoFC If my solution was interesting and/or correct then don't forget to UpVote it and/or Accept it. UpVoting is done at the top of my answer, to the left handside from it by clicking Upper triangle (arrow). Accepting is done by clicking CheckMark nearby the place of upvoting. Accepting means that answer looks right to you, that it solves the task. UpVoting means that you Liked solution and want to give extra scores to author (me). Both accepting and upvoting can be done same time. Both actions give me extra scores to raise my reputation.